# Reading data from file to JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am making a GUI in which i have 6 combo boxes, i read data from a text file to these 
combo boxes. My text file has 3 rows and 2 columns, so when i read data only my first 2 combo boxes is getting populated with data that to with the values of the 3rd row of the text file instead of the 1st row and the remaining combo boxes remains empty.As my text file contains 6 values it should display in the 6 combo boxes.Please help

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Read extends JPanel {
    public Read() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        add(buttonPanel);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2, 5, 5));

        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox1.addItem("1");
        comboBox1.addItem("2");
        comboBox1.addItem("4");

        JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox2.addItem("1");
        comboBox2.addItem("2");
        comboBox2.addItem("4");

        JComboBox comboBox3 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox3.addItem("1");
        comboBox3.addItem("2");
        comboBox3.addItem("4");

        JComboBox comboBox4 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox4.addItem("1");
        comboBox4.addItem("2");
        comboBox4.addItem("4");

        JComboBox comboBox5 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox5.addItem("1");
        comboBox5.addItem("2");
        comboBox5.addItem("4");

        JComboBox comboBox6 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox6.addItem("1");
        comboBox6.addItem("2");
        comboBox6.addItem("4");

        buttonPanel.add(comboBox1);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox2);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox3);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox4);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox5);
        buttonPanel.add(comboBox6);

        try{
            InputStream ips=new FileInputStream("tl.txt"); 
            InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
            String line;
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                String[] s = line.split(" ");
                comboBox1.setSelectedItem(s[0]);
                comboBox2.setSelectedItem(s[1]);
            }
            br.close(); 
        }       
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Read a = new Read();
        JFrame f = new JFrame("");
        f.getContentPane().add(a);
        f.setSize(300,200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

text file

```
2 4
1 2
4 1
```

Comment: You are only selecting comboBox1 and comboBox2 only

Comment: I have set s[0] and s[1] for combobox1 and combobox2 for reading first line,how do i read the send line and third line.

Comment: first read all the lines to a array or arraylist. Then iterate through that and set the items by spliting each item as you do now

Comment: As per the below code, 

   `comboBox1.setSelectedItem(s[0]);
    comboBox2.setSelectedItem(s[1]);`

the last rows values will overwrite the previous rows value. So your code is populating only the last row values.

Comment: Either read the entire data, save and then populate or store all the `comboboxes` in an array and then read line by line and get the `coboboxes` and populate.

Comment: Can u please give me an example of how to do this @Che

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a `JCombobox` array and store all your JCombobox in the array as below,

```
    JComboBox[] comboBoxs = new JComboBox[6];
    comboBoxs[0] = comboBox1;
    comboBoxs[1] = comboBox2;
    comboBoxs[2] = comboBox3;
    comboBoxs[3] = comboBox4;
    comboBoxs[4] = comboBox5;
    comboBoxs[5] = comboBox6;
```

Declare a `Arraylist` and store the data which you read from the file as below,

```
// Other code goes here.
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String line;
    while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
        String[] s = line.split(" ");
        list.add(s[0]);
        list.add(s[1]);
    }
br.close();
```

Finally loop over each `Arraylist` and populate the Combobox's.

```
for(int i = 0; i < comboBoxs.length; i++) {
        comboBoxs[i].setSelectedItem(list.get(i));
    }
```

This should do good.

Comment: Thank you,can u please suggest me how can i save the same using a button in the same format with the file from where it reads.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at your code, you are filling data only to combobox 1 and 2, other comboboxes you are not filling any data.

If you want data in other compoboxes, fill them as well in the while loop.

Hope this helps.

thanks

---

```
public class Read extends JPanel{

   String[] values=new String[6];
   JCombobox<String>[] combos=new JCombobox<String>[6];

   public Read() {

    //Do your layout initialization operations here

    this.initCombo();

    //Put the logic to add the comboboxes to the UI here

   }

   public void intiCombo(){
    try{
                ArrayList<String> tmp=new ArrayList<String>();
                InputStream ips=new FileInputStream("tl.txt"); 
                InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
                String line;
                while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                    String[] s = line.split(" ");
                    tmp.add(s[0]);
                    tmp.add(s[1]);
                }
                br.close(); 
            }       
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

         values=tmp.toArray(new String[1]);
         for(int i=0;i<conbos.length;i++)combos[i]=new JCombobox(values);

   }


    //Your main method comes here
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment

Comment: can u please tel me how to fill data to other comboboxes.

Comment: It shows error invalid method declaration:return type required public initCombo()